# Excel: Using a VLOOKUP to find the largest #'s name, if two values = use next name not the same name?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, vlookup, ranking

I have this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP((LARGE(C:C,2)),C:F,4,0)
```

It is looking through column C for the 2nd largest value and finding that value's name for a #2 ranking. For the 3rd largest value I used:

```
=VLOOKUP((Large(D:D,3)),D:F,4,0)
```

This is looking for the third largest in the data set and using its name in column F for the #3 ranking.

The problem is that the name for the #3 rank is pulling the same name for the #2 rank because they have equal values. I want the next highest value as the #3 because they are technically tied for #2 rank but I can't have two #2's.

Here's an example using a sports analogy:

Team Ranking by points:
1. Team A - 10 points
2. Team B - 9 points
3. Team C - 9 points
4. Team D - 8 points

I want team C to read as the #3 Rank but it just duplicates the #2 rank because it is reading the same value. I know I can use another criteria for separating the two equal teams, but I do not want to do that. I just want the next value in that ranking that is not a duplicate.

Thanks!

Comment: You should add a tie breaker to your data. The best way to do this might be to use a row number. (You might have to sort your worksheet to have to rows in the sequence you want.) So, if a team has 10 points and that 10 is in row 8, then you process 10.008 for your ranking. You can create a hidden column next to the points column with a formula in it, like =C+(ROW()/1000) and use that column to draw your ranking from.

Comment: Please update the screenshot of your sheet